# How to compile CIL code?

Tags: .net, assemblies, cil

I have a code written in `CIL`. Let's say, a file called `some_il_code.il` holds it. I want to compile it to create a managed `exe` assembly.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [ilasm tool.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx.aspx)

```
ilasm /exe Your.il /deb=opt
peverify /md /il Your.exe
```

ilasm compiles it, [peverify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62bwd2yd.aspx) verifies it.

Comment: Peverify makes sure your generated MSIL is correct and runs. But you have to decide for yourself if you should use it. Better be safe than sorry though.

Comment: ilasm generates your assembly if its syntactically correct. Anything else is not checked. (Type safety etc.)