# Can I compile a CIL program?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, compilation, cil

I'm going to give a deep look at [`CIL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) but before I'd like to know: can I call the CIL compiler? if so, how do I that? I read some articles about CIL but none of them mention how to compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the following forum thread, you can use Ilasm.exe (IL Assembler)

[How to compile CIL code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741607/how-to-compile-cil-code)